# Error opening '*.wav': File contains data in an unknown format

Tags: python, wav, librosa

I'm trying to run the following code:

```
import os
import librosa  
import IPython.display as ipd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.io import wavfile 
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

train_audio_path = 'train/audio/'
samples, sample_rate = librosa.load(train_audio_path+'yes/0a7c2a8d_nohash_0.wav', sr = 16000)
```

But get two errors:

```
Error opening 'train/audio/yes/0a7c2a8d_nohash_0.wav': File contains data in an unknown format
```

and

```
NoBackendError:
```

I've tried downloading ffmpeg and gstreamer to fix the second error but no luck. I'm not sure what to do about the first error as I have imported libraries that should be able to handle .wav files.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Looks very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/58810320/942774

Comment: Thank you. Gave that a go but unfortunately it didn't solve the problem