# No Backend error despite of downloading ffmpeg and setting path variable python

Tags: python, audio, ffmpeg, librosa, nobackend

I am having a no backend error in my python code to open an audio file using librosa module. I have downloaded ffmpeg and seted environment but still I am getting no backend error. I am getting this error with .mp3 extension, with wav it is working properly .

```
import librosa as lib
t,s_r=lib.load(r"C:\songs\03-BuddhuSaMann-DownloadMing.SE.mp3")
```

This is the error I am getting:

UserWarning: PySoundFile failed. Trying audioread instead.
  warnings.warn('PySoundFile failed. Trying audioread instead.')

RuntimeError: Error opening 'C:\songs\03-BuddhuSaMann-DownloadMing.SE.mp3': File contains data in an unknown format.
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

NoBackendError:

Answer (score 0):

Please try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63480393/7999026 to make sure your file is not corrupted. If it isn't and `librosa` still fails, you can try opening your file with `scipy`.

```
from scipy.io import wavfile
t,s_r = wavfile.read(r"C:\songs\03-BuddhuSaMann-DownloadMing.SE.mp3")
```